# MySQL - Find records with or without special chars

Tags: php, mysql

I've created an online shop and I noticed an issue with the search-function.
If the user enters a string to search, I do a `SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE %....%`

This works good, but the problems exists in the special charachters. Imagine I have products like "préparé" or "côte à l'os". When the user searches for "prepare" or "cote a l'os", the products won't be found, nonetheless they are in there.

The problem is also there in the other way. If the user searches for "dûroc" but my product is in the database as "duroc", he will not find it.

It can also be something in between: the users searches for "preparé" or "côte a l'os".

How can I fix this problem, or at least make it smaller?

MySQL 5.1.73 / PHP 5.6

---

**UPDATE**

I did some extra testing after reading the given answers and I can give some extra details.
If I use tools like MySQL Workbench or Sequel Pro, it all works just fine. So I can execute `SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE '%prepare%'` or `SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE '%preparé%'`; they both return every record where the description contains "prepare", "préparé" or "preparé", exactly as I want it.
I did not know MySQL did this, because SQL Server does not (just tested it)

Then back to the site. If the users types "prepare", it still goes well, all records are returned as above.
But then, if the users types "preparé", it returns nothing, not even those with "preparé" in the description.

This is the query in PHP that I use:

```
$qryPLU = sprintf(SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE "%%%s%%", $conn->real_escape_string($mywgid));
```

When I echo this I get:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE '%PREPARé%'
```

So somewhere in it's way to the database that é is changed I think, but I don't know how, where or why.

Somehow @Reversal was getting in the right direction I see now.

Comment: How about parsing search terms before querying database? You may perform several substitution, such as `é => e, ô => o`, combine them in all possible ways and then query DB with all keywords created.

Comment: You may as well substitute every special char by an underscore `_`: it is a special character matching any single character.

Comment: Tnx for thinking with me. I've also been thinking in this way, but the problem is you can't reverse it. If the users searches for "prepare", but in the DB it says "préparé", this will fail.

Comment: I've updated my question. I guess you were going in the right direction after all. How can I easily substitute every special char to underscore?

Comment: Have you checked @Strawberry answer? It seems to solve your issue. Anyway, this function should be helpful: http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: Their answers seem to work in MySQL but I don't understand how to apply in PHP :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert you php variable/parameter to ISO-8859-1 with iconv like this:

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to your `charset` and `collation`.

```
mysql> set names latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'préparé' like '%prepare%';
+------------------------------+
| 'préparé' like '%prepare%' |
+------------------------------+
|                            0 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> set names utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 'préparé' like '%prepare%';
+------------------------------+
| 'préparé' like '%prepare%' |
+------------------------------+
|                            1 |
+------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Incidentally, I can't replicate this behaviour, so it may be a bug (perhaps related to microsoft machines)

Comment: Maybe. My default names is `utf8mb4`

Comment: The only one that works for me is utf32, but the command line still displays accented characters as '?'

Comment: You can file a bug to MySQL. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what appears to work for me:

```
SELECT _utf32 'préparé' = _utf32 'prepare' collate utf32_general_ci;
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| _utf32 'pr?par?' = _utf32 'prepare' collate utf32_general_ci |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                            1 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+

select _utf32 "côte à l'os" = _utf32 "cote a l'os" collate utf32_general_ci;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| _utf32 "c?te ? l'os" = _utf32 "cote a l'os" collate utf32_general_ci |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                    1 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```